# How to synchronize two functions using a lock

Tags: c#, .net, locking

I have two functions A and B, and I want to prevent them from running simultaneously. Should I use lock or mutex or interlocked?

This is what I tried:

```
class C
{
    object obj = new Object();

    void A()
    {
        lock(obj)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    void B()
    {
        lock(obj)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

if I want A to check if B is locked and return how would I go about that?

is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have will already prevent two different threads calling `A` and `B` (on the same instance of `C`) at the same time - although note that if `A` calls `B` (or `B` calls `A`) it will work. The call will be *blocked* until it can obtain the `lock`.

If you want to **check** whether you can obtain the `lock`, without blocking - you can do that via `TryEnter` specifying a zero timeout:

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try {
    Monitor.TryEnter(obj, 0, ref lockTaken);
    if(lockTaken) {
        // have lock etc
    }
} finally {
    if(lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(obj);
}
```

Comment: marc im sorry but i didn't understand if my works (as long as I don't care if the other one will need to wait)

Comment: @NahumLitvin if you don't care that one waits while the other completes: then your code already does that. It also prevents multiple concurrent calls to the *same* method from different threads, note.

Comment: @NahumLitvin you then asked: "if I want A to check if B is locked and return how would I go about that?" - that is what the example at the bottom shows; you could of course use `if(!lockTaken) return;` if you specifically want to `return` when the `lock` is not available

Comment: WAIT so what would happen in A would call B? would that cause a deadlock?

Comment: @NahumLitvin no, `Monitor`/`lock` is re-entrant; if a thread already has the `lock` (via `A`), then it can `lock` again in `B` successfully, and will not be released until it has exited both `lock` statements. Basically, it is implemented as a counter. It is only ***other threads*** that are blocked.